# What does head down mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does it mean in this sentence please?:
 "They head down to the local pet store and have a look around."

Thx for your answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

In short, *down* when used like that is more like a manner of speech—something people just say. But typically it means downwards or in the southern direction. Some examples are in order.

Example #1:

> I live **down** in Florida.

Example #2:

> — Excuse me. Where's the closest subway station?
>   — Go **down** the street and turn left.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an idomatic collocation, *head down*, but *head* plus two stacked preposition phrases: the intransitive preposition *down* and *to the local pet store*.

*Head* here is the intransitive verb meaning "direct one's motion"; in this context it has an 'inchoative' sense: they started moving in that direction

*Down* may have a literal sense, (as in *downhill*) or a figurative sense of *toward the center* (as in *downtown*); but it is more likely to be employed here as an intensive expressing something like intentionality or purpose (as in *get down to work*).

*To the local pet store* expresses the goal of the motion.

You may paraphrase

> They set out for the local pet store with the intention of browsing the stock.